# SQL insert multiple stored procedures, without multiple inserts

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I have a stored procedure 'inserttable' that selects the information from database, where '@TableName' changes depending on company name (Company1, Company2), '@CompanyNo' is the identity numbering (1,2).

My insert:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Table1
INSERT INTO Table1
(Company, Store, POS, StoreNo)
exec inserttable(Company1,1)
exec inserttable(Company2,2)
```

My question, is it possible to insert multiple stored procedures exec?

My example  inserts only the first exec and then displays the second.

That is without having to add another insert!

EDIT:

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[inserttable] 
     @TableName varchar(300),
     @StoreNo varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
declare @q varchar(1000)
set @q = 'SELECT Company, Store, POS,'+@StoreNo+'
      FROM '+@TableName
exec (@q)
END
GO
```

EDIT 2:

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[inserttable] 
     @TableName varchar(300),
     @StoreNo varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
declare @q varchar(1000)
set @q = 'INSERT INTO TABLE Table1 (SELECT Company, Store, POS,'+@StoreNo+'
      FROM '+@TableName+')'
exec (@q)
END
GO
```

Just running the exec should do the trix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know that you can do that with stored procs, but :

a) if the insert is always the same you could put that into the stored proc so it takes the form

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(Company, Store, POS)
[current select statement from proc]
```

then just

```
exec inserttable(Company1,1)
exec inserttable(Company2,2)
```

b) replace the proc with a function that returns a table and use a union

```
create function companydata( @name varchar(50), @number integer) 
returns table
return select @name company, @number store, 1 pos
```

obviously replace the select with whatever your existing sp does, then you can run using a union

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Company, Store, POS)
select * from companydata('co no 1', 1)
union all 
select * from companydata('co no 2',2)
```